# Jquery - Want to prevent invoking popup window which is already defined

Tags: jquery, stoppropagation

I am invoking one popup window on clicking of table row.

So my code is like this...

```
$('.assignPanel tbody tr').on('click', function() {  // code for invoking the popup window });
```

The problem is here.  I dont want to invoke the same popup window while clicking on other set of 'tbody tr' where I am having class name called 'noRequiredPopup'.  How can i handle this situation?  Help please.

Comment: `function() { if (!$(this).hasClass('noRequiredPopup')) { show popup } ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : use `.not()` to filter out the `tr`with `class="noRequiredPopup"`

```
$('.assignPanel tbody tr').not('.noRequiredPopup').on('click', function() {  // code for invoking the popup window });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.assignPanel tbody tr').on('click', function() { 
    if($(this).hasClass('TheClassName')){
        // Pupup Code
    }else
        return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change css selector from:

```
$('.assignPanel tbody tr')
```

to

```
$('.assignPanel tbody tr:not(.noRequiredPopup)')
```